# AJAX get URL parameters = NULL

Tags: ajax, url, parameters

I need URL parameter from a rewritten URL (htacces).

I have this function but it returns NULL:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (results===null){
   return null;
}
else{
   return results[1] || 0;
}
};
```

And this is how I'm calling for the parameter:

```
var value = $.urlParam('profile');
```

I need to get "1" from "page.php/profile/1"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should check your RegExp

Comment: Thanks! since $_GET doesn't care about htacces I didn't figure jquery does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @weigreen's help I've modified my RegExp:

```
    var results = new RegExp('[/]' + name + '/([^#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
```

EDIT:

For multiple parameters (/profile/1/page/2) this was a better solution:

```
var results = new RegExp('[/]' + name + '/([a-z0-9]+)').exec(window.location.href);
```